# How to show all information from sql query

Tags: sql

i have a sql query, but i have problem with this, i would like that the sql query show me all the information in both table that i have...
And it works, but when i put a condition in the sentence, i can't have the full info...

With this query, i can see all information of my table, even if i don't have info in some columns... And i need that, but i want to add a condition, and when i add the condition i can't see all.

Result:
[Query without condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO1s8.png)

```
SELECT dbo.tblHoras.IdHora, dbo.tblHoras.Hora, dbo.tblHoras.Meta, COUNT(dbo.tblProductos.Serial) as Cantidad
FROM tblHoras full join
     tblProductos
     ON tblHoras.IdHora = tblProductos.IdHora
GROUP By tblHoras.IdHora, tblHoras.Hora, tblHoras.Meta
ORDER By tblHoras.IdHora;
```

And this is the query with the condition, and this doesn't bring me all the info.

```
SELECT dbo.tblHoras.IdHora, dbo.tblHoras.Hora, dbo.tblHoras.Meta, COUNT(dbo.tblProductos.Serial) as Cantidad
FROM tblHoras full join
     tblProductos
     ON tblHoras.IdHora = tblProductos.IdHora
WHERE tblProductos.ActualFecha = '2017-04-19'
GROUP By tblHoras.IdHora, tblHoras.Hora, tblHoras.Meta
ORDER By tblHoras.IdHora;
```

Result:
[Query with condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPrms.png)

Comment: please tag appropriate database thanks

Comment: can you please post the .ActualFecha  data and data type

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` with filtering is really confusing.  You should provide same data and desired results.

Comment: Where clause filters the data based on the condition. That's why you might be seeing less data. You need to the value of ActualFetcha in first result. There should be only 3 rows with the value you are passing in where clause. And those rows are being displayed as part of second query result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you are aggregating only by columns in `tblHoras`, I think you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT h.IdHora, h.Hora, h.Meta, COUNT(p.Serial) as Cantidad
FROM tblHoras h LEFT JOIN
     tblProductos p
     ON p.IdHora = p.IdHora AND p.ActualFecha = '2017-04-19'
GROUP By h.IdHora, h.Hora, h.Meta
ORDER By h.IdHora;
```

The filtering condition should then be in the `ON` clause.

Notice that I also introduced table aliases which make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you for the observation, It works now, I really appreciate it.